# Can't get Tauri and React to show my content

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tsx, tauri

I'm trying to build an app with Tauri and React. I am new to both these technologies and trying to build a dekstop app with these.

Now I have a loginscreen with a bunch of content, I believe what is in there doesn't really matter. But I just can't get it to show. The page just remains fully white.

My `App.tsx` looks like this:

```
import LoginScreen from '../Screens/LoginScreen';

export default LoginScreen;
```

My `main.tsx` looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App/App";
import "./styles.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And my `index.html` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tauri + React + TS</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="src/App/App.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is it not showing anything? I also can't find any errors except when I check the console in my browser which says:

```
:1420/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-native.js?v=26781060:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep)
```

I made sure all my node modules are up to date but this didn't change anything. What can I do to fix this?

If clarification is needed, please let me know.

Comment: What's a Tau'ri?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Tauri uses Vite. If you were to use Vite directly I'd say you go with "yarn vite --force" so it can redo optimizations. Ultimately you can always just remove the folder ".vite" from node_modules.